# ChromeCustomTab passkeys unexpected behaviour on finger input

Tags: android, react-native, expo, webauthn, passkey

I am experimenting passkeys but I have very strange problem.
From my Expo mobile app I open a ChromeCustomTab
It points to a web application that does webauthN.create
Than Android prompts me for passkey creation.
I accept, than it opens the finger input and I put my finger on.
At this point it back to the mobile app instead of the ChromeCustomTabs.
I tried this with 4 different smartphone with different behaviours:

OnePlus Nord, Android 12, has the issue
OnePlus Nord 2 android 14 has the issue
Xiaomi lineagesOS android 13 works as expected
Oppo phone android 12 works as expected

Any idea? I am scared about this